# Designing a battery-powered hair dryer

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, heat, charging

So I am basically just trying to figure out how long a battery-powered hair dryer would last to see if this would make sense as a concept project.

The best energy density I found to reasonably fit inside a hair dryer would be using 4x 2170 Lithium cells.
[Spec Link](https://bigbattery.com/product/model-3-2170-cells-w-cap-box/)

I'm just not sure how to calculate the energy draw on nichrome wire. (Unless there is a better heating element alternative) The specs usually give the highest Watt rating of the wires, but what specs will I need to include in the equation to calculate battery life?

I am assuming that the actual amount of heat generated will depend on the rate in which you draw power from the batteries.. my brain is hurting!

Comment: Start with the basics. How much energy does your batteries contain?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How long should 8, 1.5V batteries last for?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/232646/how-long-should-8-1-5v-batteries-last-for)

Comment: Look at the power rating of corded hairdriers ... several hundred watts to upwards of 1 kW.

Answer (score 3):

If you design the hair dryer so that air is pulled past the batteries first, then blown through the heating wire, you will be able to extract all the heat from the process of discharging the batteries, including what would otherwise be considered waste heat.

The relevant spec will then be Watt-hours (Wh). Doing the math from this is easy:

- Your 4.8 Ah 3.7 V cells have 4.8 * 3.7 = 17.76 Wh.
- Four cells is then 17.76 * 4 = 71.04 Wh.
- At one kilowatt of heating, this will give you a runtime of 17.04 Wh / 1000 W = 0.017 hours.
- 0.017 hours * 60 minutes per hour = a total runtime of 1.02 minutes.

Of course this calculation doesn't say anything about the ratio between heat dissipated in the heating wire, and "waste" heat from the internal resistance of the batteries.

Also, the power draw of the fan is not included, but the "waste" heat from the motor would also contribute to heating the air, so the end result would be roughly the same.

Other specs, like maximum continuous discharge current, maximum operating temperature, and factors like battery degradation over time, safety factor, etc, would also need to be taken into consideration.

Comment: Conclusion: since a hairdryer that works for only one minute is inutile, a battery powered hairdryer doesn't make sense.

Comment: Agreed. However a 250 W hairdryer would be able to run for 4 minutes. And a 250 W hairdryer with twice the battery capacity would run for 8 minutes. I'm guessing that 250 W is too weak for most people, and 8 batteries is too bulky for most people. I for one wouldn't buy it, but who knows, maybe marketing can come up with something. ;]

Comment: I propose a propane powered one, I tell you hwat!

Comment: My wife had a 1700W hairdryer and sometimes she complained that it was "weak". She bought a new one which claims to be 1900W and now she is sort of sactisfied. I doubt that one with 1000 W, and heavy batteries, could make someone happy. My wife wouldn't be, I'm sure that.

Comment: Those batteries will explode if you have them run a 14.8VDC to mains AC voltage inverter because the battery current might be 81A! Why does anybody need a portable hairdryer anyway?